# SQL Where only 1 specific string exists

Tags: sql, where-clause

If I have the below table called `Sales`, how would one create an SQL query to pull the data for transactions where only `chocolate` was sold.

The required and expected output would be (transaction IDs 1 and 4 only):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why row number 3 is excluded from result?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @JaydipJadhav: because in transaction with ID = 3 Crisps where also sold

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want transactions where chocolate was sold but nothing else. The declarative way to do that would be:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS [Transaction ID Count], 
    SUM([Sales Value]) AS [Sales Value]
FROM Sales
WHERE Item = 'Chocolate' 
AND [Transaction ID] NOT IN
(
SELECT [Transaction ID]  FROM Sales
WHERE Item <> 'Chocolate' 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three transaction in your example  where Chocolate was sold, this will pull data from 3 rows.

```
select count(transaction_ID), sum(sales_value) from sales
where item  =  'Chocolate';
```

or 
this excludes transaction id 3

```
select count(transaction_ID), sum(sales_value) from sales s1
where item  =  'Chocolate'
and transaction in
(select transaction id from  
(select transaction_id, count(*) cnt from sales)
where cnt =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TransactionID, SUM(SaleValue)
FROM TableName t1
WHERE Item = 'Chocolate' 
      AND NoT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM TableName t2 
                      WHERE t1.TransactionID = t2.TransactionID AND t2.Item <> 'Chocolate')
```

Comment: . . . You should removed `SaleValue = 1` & use `SUM(SaleValue)` instead of `COUNT()`

Answer (score 0):

select count(*), transaction_id
where Item = 'Chocolate'
group by transaction_id
having count(*) = 1;